# Unable to access List[ArrayList] in play 2 framework template

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am populating `List<ArraList>` in "model" as below:

```
List<ArrayList> selectedAgrovoc=new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
for(int i.......)
{
for(int j......)
{
ArrayList rowNewAgrovoc=new ArrayList();
rowNewAgrovoc.add(new String(....));
rowNewAgrovoc.add(new String(.....));
selectedAgrovoc.add(rowNewAgrovoc);
}

}
```

Accessing List in Controller:

```
inputModel create=filledForm.get();
List<ArrayList> ctagsList=inputModel.indertData(create);
return ok(summary.render(create, ctagsList));
```

In template field:

```
@(ctagList: List[ArrayList])
```

After compilation I get error `class ArrayList takes type parameters`

My Questions are:

1. Why I am not able to access `List` in template
2. How can I display each element in `List` using `for` loop in template

Comment: This is a Java problem, not a playframework one. You should consider reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: @kheraud - any suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: Learning Java generics. "ArrayList takes type parameters" --> new ArrayList<String>(); (can be shortened with java 1.7)

Answer (score 1):

Below @(ctagList: List[ArrayList]), Add @import collection.JavaConversions._ and declare ctagList as an arralist - @(ctagList: ArrayList[Long])